# Why Vendor ID & Product ID of Arduino Micro (USB Device) are different in Linux and Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ubuntu, arduino

I'm developing a software that comunicate with an Arduino Micro using Qt for C++.

I'm using QSerialPortInfo to show some information of my Arduino Micro with this method:

```
for (QSerialPortInfo info : QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts())
{
   qDebug() << "Port Name   :" << info.portName();
   qDebug() << "Description :" << info.description();
   qDebug() << "Manufacturer:" << info.manufacturer();
   qDebug() << "Vendor ID   :" << info.vendorIdentifier();
   qDebug() << "Product ID  :" << info.productIdentifier();
}
```

In Windows 10 this is the result:

> Port Name   : "COM4" Description : "Arduino Micro" Manufacturer:
>   "Arduino LLC (www.arduino.cc)" **Vendor ID   : 9025 Product ID  : 32823**

And in Ubuntu 15:

> Port Name   : "ttyACM0" Description : "Arduino Micro" Manufacturer:
>   "Arduino LLC" **Vendor ID   : 5549 Product ID  : 1908**

Why Vendor & Manufacter are differents ? I think the IDs are about the device so must still be the same, platform independent .. I'm wrong ?

If I want to check if a device is my device how can I do it ? I wanted to do a simple check with a Vendor & Product ID

UPDATE:

I forget to tell that I'm using Ubuntu with a Virtual Machine on Windows10 with VMWare (if it can change something)

Comment: Are you possibly getting device driver information?

Comment: @NathanOliver which kind of driver information ? In windows I have installed the drivers with the arduino IDE, in Ubuntu the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your virtual machine has a virtual serial port, and the virtual serial port has a virtual vendor ID. 5549 is hex 15AD, which is VMWare,Inc.

Comment: You Are right! thanks, I didn't know that the virtual machine had a virtual serial port.